# Why an exponential graph can't have b equal to 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I've seen that the graph of an exponential function, $f(x) = a\cdot b^x$, cannot have $b$ equal $1$.  Why is this?

I think it's because the function would be a flat line if $b=1$.  Is this true?

Comment: Not everyone uses the same variable names.  In what context are you using $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Y=a*b^x where a>0 and b>0 but $\neq$ 1.

Comment: $y=ab^x$ is a straight line if $b=1$

Comment: @Karl yes it will be a straight line if $b=1$

Comment: Typo sorry read maths latex as $y=a^{bx }$

Comment: Who said it cannot be 1?

Comment: Somewhere for me, and it's what, not who.

Comment: I guess it's "not exponential" in the sense that its limit behavior is not like that of any other $b>0$, because $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow \pm \infty} \neq 0$; just trying to think what whoever wrote/said that had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $1^x=1$ for all $x$. Hence if $b = 1$ we have that
$$f(x) = a\cdot b^x = a\cdot 1^x = a\cdot 1 = a $$
is a straight horizontal line of height $a$.

Comment: What's wrong with a straight horizontal line? I'm sure there is a mathematical reason, and the actual reason does not include inconvenience

Comment: @AllanHenriques There is nothing really *wrong* with it per se. It just behaves much differently from other values of $b$. For $b = 1$, $f(x)$ is constant. For other values it isn't. (For values $0<b<1$ the function is decreasing with $x$, and for $b>1$ it is increasing with $x$, and for $b = 1$ it is constant with $x$)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the variable $b$ is 1, that just defeats the equation. We know that one times all numbers is that number, so the other variable $a$, multiplied by one, would be $a$.